# How to exlude cases from Regex?

Tags: regex

Let's say I have the following text:

```
Lorem Ipsum
Lorem Ipsum Dolor
Lorem Dolor Ipsum Sit Amet
```

I want to get the all the `Ipsum's` but does not starting with `Dolor`

What should be the correct regex to match this condition?

Comment: Is the presence of the "Lorem" guaranteed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest the following regex pattern which would match `Ipsum` which is not immediately preceded by `Dolor`:

```
(?:^\s*|\b(?!Dolor)\S+\s+)Ipsum
```

It may also match a preceding word (not `Dolor`), should `Ispum` not be the very first word in the line.  Hopefully this would be enough for you to use in your IntelliJ search.

I recommend against using a negative lookbehind here, because to cover all cases you might need a variable width lookbehind, which may not be supported and which probably would be inefficient.

### Demo

Comment: I am using IntelliJ find tool with regex.

Answer (score 0):

Negative lookbehind is what you're looking for:

```
(?<!Dolor )Ipsum
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hXyrAV/1)

Comment: What happens if there could be more than space after `Dolor`?

Comment: Then it's not a proper sentence and we need clarification from OP if this is a case.

Comment: No it is only one space guaranteed.